# showing that $v=\text{constant}$ are geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $E$, $F$ and $G$ be the first fundamental coefficients of the surface metric (more specifically, $ds^2=Edu^2+2Fdudv+Gdv^2$). Show that if $E$, $F$ and $G$ are functions of $u$ only and $\frac{F^2}{E}$ is constant, then the parametric curves $v=\text{constant}$ are all geodesics.

$===================================$

We know that if $$V=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{v}}\bigg)-\frac{\partial T}{\partial v}=0$$
where $T=\frac{1}{2}(E\dot{u}^2+2F\dot{u}\dot{v}+G\dot{v}^2)$ and $t$ is the parameter, dot defines the parametric differentiation, then $v=\text{constant}$ will be geodesic. We are given that $$\frac{\partial E}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial G}{\partial v}=0$$ and $$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{F^2}{E}\bigg)=0$$
I calculated $V$ as follows $$V=\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\dot{u}^2+F\ddot{u}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial u}\dot{v}^2+G\ddot{v}$$
and stuck afterwards, as I don't see a way to prove $V=0$ using the fact that $\frac{F^2}{E}$ is constant. Is it a correct approach? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need a companion Lagrangian equation for the $u$ derivatives as well?

Comment: Why? We need to show only for $v=\text{constant}$ curves.

Comment: But if $v$ is constant, everything becomes a function of $u(t)$. So I don't see your logic. To verify that $v=v_0$ is a geodesic, you must check *both* Lagrangian equations hold when $v=v_0$.